# System.NotSupportedException while calling captureSource.Start() in wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

**System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported**
I'm getting this error sometimes while calling Start method of captureSource to record video on windows phone 8.

Below is my code :

```
if (captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice != null
                    && captureSource.State == CaptureState.Started)
                {
                    captureSource.Stop();
                    //UpdateUI(ButtonState.Recording, "Initializing...");

                    //Create Dir If Not Exist
                    if (!IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().DirectoryExists(FileLocation))
                        IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication().CreateDirectory(FileLocation);

                    DateTime theDate = DateTime.Now;
                    isoVideoFileName = theDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "_" + theDate.ToString("HHmmss") + "_" + "Video" + "." + GlobalDTO.VideoFormat;

                    // Connect the input and output of fileSink.
                    captureSource = new CaptureSource();
                    captureSource.CaptureFailed += new EventHandler<ExceptionRoutedEventArgs>(OnCaptureFailed);
                    captureSource.CaptureImageCompleted += captureSource_CaptureImageCompleted;

                    fileSink.CaptureSource = captureSource;
                    fileSink.IsolatedStorageFileName = FileLocation + isoVideoFileName;
                }

                // Begin recording.
                if (captureSource.VideoCaptureDevice != null
                    && captureSource.State == CaptureState.Stopped)
                {
                    videoRecorderBrush.SetSource(captureSource);

                    captureSource.Start();
                    captureSource.CaptureImageAsync();
                }

                // Set the button states and the message.
                UpdateUI(ButtonState.Recording, "Recording...");
```

Comment: You need to capture the exception details and put them in an [edit]. That doesn't mean taking a picture of them, btw.

Comment: I caught the exception but found that InnerException is null , Message is "Specified method is not supported." and Source is "System.Windows".

Comment: Call stack.  You have to learn that the exception details contain everything you need to track down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

That feature may not be supported on all phones? 
That maybe why you are getting that exception. you should catch the exception and handle it in an appropriate way to inform the user the functionality is not supported.

Comment: Thanks Timmy, but my code is working and I'm getting this error sometimes instead everytime.